# Perl: Combine two JSONs

Tags: json, perl

I am looking for help/guidance to combine multiple JSON into 1 JSON based on a node in PERL. For example here are the two JSON content that I want to combine.

**JSON #1:**

```
{
    "title": "All",
    "lastModified": "2017-04-11T00:00:00.000+0000",
    "users": [{
            "name": "Alpha One",
            "title": "Security Chief",
            "locations": [{"id": "730WLCS"}, {"id": "943MCS"}]
        },
        {
            "name": "Alpha Two",
            "title": "Security Manager"
        }
    ]
}
```

**JSON #2:**

```
{
    "title": "All",
    "lastModified": "2017-04-11T00:00:00.000+0000",
    "users": [{
            "name": "Beta One",
            "title": "Architect",
            "locations": [{"id": "730WLCS"}]
        }
    ]
}
```

**RESULT JSON :**

```
{
    "title": "All",
    "lastModified": "2017-04-11T00:00:00.000+0000",
    "users": [{
            "name": "Alpha One",
            "title": "Security Chief",
            "locations": [{"id": "730WLCS"}, {"id": "943MCS"}]
        },
        {
            "name": "Alpha Two",
            "title": "Security Manager"
        },
        {
            "name": "Beta One",
            "title": "Architect",
            "locations": [{"id": "730WLCS"}]
        }
    ]
}
```

Basically, I want to combine only the "users" node.

I tried to get the node using from_json and tried to push into an array, but it is not working.
Here is the code that I tried:

```
my $json_obj1 = from_json($json_txt1, {utf8 => 1});
my $json_obj2 = from_json($json_txt2, {utf8 => 1});

push(@myJSON, @{$json_obj1->{'users'}});
push(@myJSON, @{$json_obj2->{'users'}});
```

Any help is much appreciated. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
my $json_obj1 = decode_json($json_txt1);  # Same as from_json($json_txt1, {utf8 => 1})
my $json_obj2 = decode_json($json_txt2);

push @{ $json_obj2->{users} }, @{ $json_obj1->{users} };
```

If you want to remove duplicates , keeping the newer records (assuming `$json_obj1` is the older state), you can use the following:

```
my %seen;
@{ $json_obj2->{users} } =
   grep !$seen{$_->{name}}++,
      @{ $json_obj2->{users} },
      @{ $json_obj1->{users} };
```

Comment: Thanks @ikegami for the response.
I tried as the following `my $final = encode_json(\@myJSON);` and this helped to resolve the issue.